# How can I select all post with a specific hashtag that a user is following in SQL & PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

In the Database I have a table with all hashtags ([Table hashtag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSFph.png)) and the user_id that is following the hashtag. In another table I saved the posts with a description with the hashtags ([Table photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5PrL.png)).
Now, I want to select all posts with a specific hashtag when a user is following that hashtag. How can I do this?

Comment: "select all post" - is `post` another table?

Comment: Is my annswer correct?If so pls mark as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Using sql,

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "databaseName")//replacing username,password,databasename  with the appropriate values;
  $mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");
} catch(Exception $e) {
  error_log($e->getMessage());
  exit('Error connecting to database'); //Should be a message a typical user could understand
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE hashtag = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['hashtag']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows === 0) exit('No rows');
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $posts[] = $row['posts'];//or whatever the row of the posts body is

}

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $row["posts"]. " " . $row["hashtag"]. "<br>";
    }
}
else{
echo 'NO RESULTS FOUND!!';
}

$stmt->close();
?>
```